# How to pass the value in AJAX without refreshing with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here i want do file validation after that all value pass next page through AJAX so trying like this but i can't get correct answer,suppose select city field and click the button meaans page is refreshing but my condition don't want to refresh the page how can do this?

```js
function validateForm() {
      var city = document.forms["myForm"]["city"].value;
       if (city == null || city == "") {
         document.getElementById("state_err").innerHTML = "Select Your State";
      return false;
      }
   else{
   $.ajax({
   url:'search_truck.php',
   type:'POST',
   data : { 'state_id' : city},
   success:function(data){
    //var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
    console.log(data);
   },
   });
            //return true;
             /*var formData = new FormData();
             var formData = new FormData($('#newUserForm')[0]);
             formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);*/
   }
  }
```

```html
<form id="basicForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <div class="col-md-4">
                   <select name="city" id="city" onchange="getCity(this.value);" class="form-control intro-form-fixer">
                        <option value="">Select City</option>
                        <?php
                        include("dbconfig.php");
                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM state_list");
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['state'];?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="state_err"></span>

                </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select class="form-control intro-form-fixer" autocomplete="off" name="area" id="area" style="width:100%;">
                     <option value="">Select Area</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
    <button type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-success">SEARCH</button>
                </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use preventDefault();

So, get the form on submit and pass the event to the callback. Then call preventDefault() on the variable.

Because you're sending the data to the server, why not validate it there and then return the errors?

```js
$('#basicForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    validateForm();
});

function validateForm() {
    var city = document.forms["myForm"]["city"].value;
    if (city == null || city == "") {
        document.getElementById("state_err").innerHTML = "Select Your State";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'search_truck.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'state_id': city},
            success: function (data) {
                //var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
        //return true;
        /*var formData = new FormData();
         var formData = new FormData($('#newUserForm')[0]);
         formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);*/
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="basicForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select name="city" id="city" onchange="getCity(this.value);" class="form-control intro-form-fixer">
            <option value="">Select City</option>
            <?php
                        include("dbconfig.php");
                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM state_list");
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['state'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="state_err"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control intro-form-fixer" autocomplete="off" name="area" id="area" style="width:100%;">
            <option value="">Select Area</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-success">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Still page is refreshing